# Pulling JSON data from a website with Python 3.x

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to pull some `JSON` data from a website for a little program i'm making for a Discord bot. the code currently looks like:

```
if message.content.startswith("!jsontest"):
    import requests
    data = requests.get('http://schoolido.lu/api/cards/799/').json()
    print(data)
```

I've also tried with urllib.request.urlopen, but I'm getting a `403` error no matter which method I use. Here's the output:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 259, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Bot.py", line 177, in on_message
    response = ur.urlopen("http://schoolido.lu/api/cards/799/")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 471, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 581, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 509, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 589, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Am I just missing something, or is that code wrong? I've tried a bunch of other examples from SO, but none of them did anything different, i.e i still get a `403`.

Comment: Have you tried to pass a User-Agent header: `data = requests.get('http://schoolido.lu/api/cards/799/', headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36"}).json()`?

Comment: Yep, same 403 error.

Comment: Is it possible that your IP is blocked due to abuse of the API? Try from another IP if possible.

Comment: So I figured that I wasn't doing anything wrong, on a hunch, I remoted into my desktop and ran it from there. My hotel wifi is adding something/blocking me from pulling requests. The code works normally from my home computer. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it into a python dictionary first, like this. It should work.

```
if message.content.startswith("!jsontest"):
import requests
import json
data = requests.get('http://schoolido.lu/api/cards/799/')
text = data.text
dictionary = json.loads(text)
print(data)
```